# C++ to create a Game for Nintendo DS

Tags: c++, windows, nintendo-ds

Well, I'm trying to do a small game for DS-DSi in C++. Just for fun and feel happy.

I was wondering if there is any guide or I could get some help with getting started. I have no clue how it works or how to make it boot on the DS.

Thanks~

Comment: try to ask here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: welcome aboard, fellow homebrew'er :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest getting a nds flash cart, like the [cycloDS](http://cyclods.wikidot.com/) (for the DS) or an [R4i](http://www.dsir4i.com/) (for the DSi). Thats how you can run your creations on the actual device.

Here is a good list of tutorials starting from the beginning (setting up your environment, getting the armKit etc) on DS development.

Tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20111219201907/http://dev-scene.com/NDS/Tutorials

Comment: Well i did it, i included all files on VC include folder. i do #include <nds.h> and it includes, also appears with autocomplete. but when i do videoSetMode() (If i'm correct it was that) it gives error. O_o

Comment: Hmm well I hope you figure the error out. I had no issues when i set it up, it was about a year or so ago.

Comment: Now this leads to a "Your computer has been infected with a virus" scam.